# remove lines from a file based on another file

Tags: perl, shell, awk

I have 2 tab separated files which look like below.

First file :-

```
raj    krishna    2345      19041884
dev    sri        1573      13894083
dev    ravi       1232      54445434
```

Second file :-

```
dev    sri        1573      42334334
kar    ham        3214      45354354
```

I want to remove any lines in first file which match the first 3 fields in second file. So, the output first file after removing should look like below.

```
raj    krishna    2345      19041884
dev    ravi       1232      54445434
```

Can anybody tell how i can achieve this in perl or shell scripting.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This makes it:

```
$ awk 'NR == FNR{a[$3];next} !($3 in a)' file2 file1
raj    krishna    2345      19041884
dev    ravi       1232      54445434
```

It firstly saves the 3rd field of file2. Then prints the lines or file1 not having this 3rd field.

It is based in the [two-file processing](http://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/).

Comment: Thanks for your response. The above uses only the 3rd field. If i want to use 1st, 2nd and 3rd fields together to remove the lines, how can i change the above script?

Comment: @srikanth You may change every `$3` for `$1,$2,$3`. For example, `{a[$1,$2,$3];next}`.

Answer (score 1):

A Perl solution. I packaged it as a test so you can... test it.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use autodie qw( open);

use Test::More tests => 1;

# I initialize the data within the test
# the real code would skip this, and open the real files instead

my $file1="raj  krishna 2345    19041884
dev sri 1573    13894083
dev ravi    1232    54445434
";

my $file2="dev  sri 1573    42334334
kar ham 3214    45354354
";

my $expected="raj   krishna 2345    19041884
dev ravi    1232    54445434
";

my $file_out;

open( my $in1, '<', \$file1);    # read from a string
open( my $in2, '<', \$file2);
open( my $out, '>', \$file_out); # write to a string

# below is the real code    

# load the list of "records" to remove
# for each line take the first 3 fields (anything except a tab followed by a tab, 3 times)
my %to_remove= map { line_to_key( $_) => 1 } <$in2>; 

while( my $line=<$in1>)
  { print {$out} $line unless $to_remove{line_to_key( $line)}; }

close $out;

# test whether we got what we wanted
is( $file_out, $expected, 'basic test');

# the "key": split on tab, then join the first 3 fields, again tab separated
sub line_to_key
  { my( $line)= @_;
    my @fields= split /\t/, $line;
    my $key= join "\t", @fields[0..2];
    return $key;
  }
```